# That middle pedal on piano

Tags: piano, keyboard-pedals

Given that the middle pedal, when there is a middle one, has a very different use on each side of the Atlantic - sustain on the left, practice on the right- and it features in some answers on this site, it would be good to find out what sort of proportions exist. I guess most grand pianos might have a sostenuto,(?) but the split for uprights (studio pianos)? And where in the world *is* there a proliferation of what?

Comment: Data point for me: the upright piano in my house *has no middle pedal at all*, and I live in North America.

Comment: Wait what? Can you be more clear about this middle pedal difference? Almost every acoustic and digital piano I’ve played that has a middle pedal has a middle pedal that does the exact same thing: sostenuto - holds up the dampers that are up when the pedal is pressed. I’ve only ever seen one kind of (upright) piano that does anything different.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that's most likely because you're in US, as I said. In UK and Europe (at least), it would appear the middle pedal works as a quiet practice pedal. It brings a curtain across between the hammers and the strings, making the sound much quieter, without affecting *how* the notes are pressed down. My studio piano is one such - made in Malaysia, I believe, in the '50s, by Yamaha, so not a cheap copy! But I feel that that's the norm here, while the norm where you are is not to have that facility - a very useful one nevertheless - but a sostenuto - an even better facility, I think.

Comment: @Duston - that's a new one on me! I thought the sostenuto pedal operated for ALL notes across the piano. As in your last sentence. Interesting!

Comment: Wait, what does your *left* pedal do? A quick overview of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_pedals suggests that "it varies," especially the earlier in piano-building history we're talking. I'm not sure how much we can generalize by location. Sounds to me there are four main purposes for pedals: sustain, sostenuto, una corda, and "practice." Seems like the right is usually sustain, but seems to me just from reading the article like the rest is up for grabs?

Comment: @AndyBonner - I've only ever come across pianos where the right pedal is damper - for sustain, and left is the 'quiet' pedal - so -called una corda, a misnomer on uprights, but there we go. It's the middle that's in contention, in my experience only the choice between practice and sostenuto. So, yes, 4 uses, only 3 pedals... Unless someone knows better!

Comment: Right is always sustain, left is always ‘soft’, though this is achieved differently on grand and upright pianos.  I have known several upright studio pianos (meaning located in a recording studio) where the middle pedal introduced not a felt damper but a set of ‘jangle’ strips, for the ‘honky-tone’ sound.

Comment: @Laurence - this seems to have opened a can of worms. Not heard of that one either. Saves putting drawing pins in the hammers, I guess! The strips probably used the 'practice' mechanism to achieve that.

Comment: FWIW, I'm in the USA, but my Schimmel upright insists on following the traditions of its native land of Braunschweig.  It has a practice pedal in the middle (with a felt damper) and a soft pedal on the left (of the type that reduces hammer motion.  My mother's Sohmer (from about 1979) has a middle pedal that does a fake sostenuto by lifting dampers on the bass register strings.

Comment: On older pianos the mute thing was usually a stop. And sostenuto on uprights is often reduced to a split sostenuto on old uprights, if it exists at all. Then, there is also these things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_piano

Comment: @Lazy - another can  of worms. But I'm considering the 'standard' piano, rather than these sophisticated ones .

Comment: Not sure if Yamaha uprights with the practice felt are a European thing, they might just be a Yamaha educational thing. Practice rooms at one Virginia university had those last time I was there. Are you asking only about uprights? If so this question makes more sense to me. Uprights seem to have strange alternatives to sostenuto. I guess the upright action doesn’t work as well for sostenuto? Or maybe upright players aren’t good enough to use it?

Comment: This article seems to agree with my notion that it’s not US versus Europe but varies by maker: https://pianopricepoint.com/the-sostenuto-pedal/

Comment: @Laurence - I loved those pianos. There was one at Lime Grove. They made a glorious sound: quite different from drawing pins as they went on jangling gently and haphazardly, after the initial key-stroke. I wonder if they were ever sampled.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - seems like you've found the answer. Don't leave it just as a comment!

Comment: this is mindblowing to me. I thought the international standard was damper on the right.

Comment: @plurple - it is - just like the accelerator on vehicles! Soft (una corda) on the left. But in US in particular, there's a middle pedal, called a sostenuto, which acts like a specific damper. In Europe, the middle pedal is more usually a practice pedal, bringing a curtain down between hammers and strings, making it possible to play very quietly, but using the same force on the keys.